# How to join two ubuntu machines to a single domain

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04

I have two ubuntu machines with IPs 2.2.2.2 and 7.7.7.7

Both the machines are pingable from each other.

Now I want to give a name to these two machines so that if i can ping the name it should ping the IP.

EX: Name of 2.2.2.2 --- machine1
    Name of 7.7.7.7 --- machine2

From 2.2.2.2:
       ping machine2 --- should be able to ping 7.7.7.7

From 7.7.7.7:
       ping machine1 --- should be able to ping 2.2.2.2

Can anyone please help?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general network tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an entry into the /etc/hosts file on each machine giving the details for the other machine. for example on 2.2.2.2 add the following:

```
7.7.7.7  name_of_machine2
```

and on 7.7.7.7:

```
2.2.2.2  name_of_machine1
```

You will want to make sure that both machines have a hostname configured. You can change the hostname by editing the  /etc/hostname file.

You should probably be using a private network for these machines, something like 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.7.